# Quickblox Chat: joining muc returns no response

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, smack, quickblox

I'm facing a problem with the quickblox XMPP-Server in combination with java aSmack library.

Persistent Multi User Chat (No password, public) was created before. so it definitly exists.
When I want to join the MUC, I "sometimes" get a "no response"-Exception.

This exception doesn't occur permanently... few tries later it works like a charm.

How do I solve this issue? Or is it a quickblox problem?

Comment: I am also facing this issue